# sg_map & lsscsi showing old storage version

Tags: linux, storage, iscsi, lun

I am using SUN storage and recently upgraded/refreshed my ISCSI LUN storage.

We have replicated old storage to new storage and attached to our servers.

I can see at SUN storage side that storage is attached to server and also from server when I run the below command it prints the following output :

```
iscsiadm -m session
tcp: [1] 10.1.1.10:3260,2 iqn.86-03.com.sun:02:afsfsf58-c56a-6ba8-a944-addd258687cd
```

The above storage is **SUN STORAGE** **7420**

But when I run sg_map or lsscsi command it prints different version:

```
lsscsi
    disk    SUN      Sun Storage 7410 1.0   /dev/sda
    disk    SUN      Sun Storage 7410 1.0   /dev/sdb
    disk    SUN      Sun Storage 7410 1.0   /dev/sdc
    disk    SUN      Sun Storage 7410 1.0   /dev/sdd
```

Output of ls on "/dev/disk/by-path/"

```
ls -1 /dev/disk/by-path/
ip-10.1.1.10:3260-iscsi-iqn.86-03.com.sun:02:afsfsf58-c56a-6ba8-a944-addd258687cd-lun-0
ip-10.1.1.10:3260-iscsi-iqn.86-03.com.sun:02:afsfsf58-c56a-6ba8-a944-addd258687cd-lun-0-part1
ip-10.1.1.10:3260-iscsi-iqn.86-03.com.sun:02:afsfsf58-c56a-6ba8-a944-addd258687cd-lun-18
ip-10.1.1.10:3260-iscsi-iqn.86-03.com.sun:02:afsfsf58-c56a-6ba8-a944-addd258687cd-lun-18-part1
ip-10.1.1.10:3260-iscsi-iqn.86-03.com.sun:02:afsfsf58-c56a-6ba8-a944-addd258687cd-lun-2
ip-10.1.1.10:3260-iscsi-iqn.86-03.com.sun:02:afsfsf58-c56a-6ba8-a944-addd258687cd-lun-2-part1
ip-10.1.1.10:3260-iscsi-iqn.86-03.com.sun:02:afsfsf58-c56a-6ba8-a944-addd258687cd-lun-4
ip-10.1.1.10:3260-iscsi-iqn.86-03.com.sun:02:afsfsf58-c56a-6ba8-a944-addd258687cd-lun-4-part1
ip-10.1.1.10:3260-iscsi-iqn.86-03.com.sun:02:afsfsf58-c56a-6ba8-a944-addd258687cd-lun-6
ip-10.1.1.10:3260-iscsi-iqn.86-03.com.sun:02:afsfsf58-c56a-6ba8-a944-addd258687cd-lun-6-part1
```

I have rebooted server twice but still I am getting the same output as given above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that it's a replication issue as you have replicated the storage , not sure just verify if you have any other host and attache the storage initiator there and check.

Comment: Exactly the problem is due to replication but still I am not sure why it is showing the old storage number instead it should display the new version. Any clue what can be done. I understand the issue but not sure how to fix this now. I checked everything from Storage side and everything is fine no issue at all. Probably I can do something on Linux host but not sure what and how.